# MongoDB - Find unique names in collection

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

let's assume I have collection like this

```
var list= [{name : "Bob", age : "22"},{name : "John", age : "21"}, {name : "Pedro", age : "15"}, {name : "Bob", age : "11"}, {name : "Mark", age : "24"}]
```

How to find using MongoDB with map-reduce and aggregation-framework unique names? 
Result should be : John,Pedro,Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [$distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) (Will return all unique values)

```
db.collection.distinct("name")
```

---

```
[
    "Bob",
    "John",
    "Pedro",
    "Mark"
]
```

**MongoDB aggregation:** [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) where you can filter after grouping values
(Note: Aggregation returns list of {key:value} object)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      count: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      unique: {
        $push: "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

---

```
[
  {
    "unique": [
      "Pedro",
      "Mark",
      "John"
    ]
  }
]
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZWOnoweH5Gc)